# What is windows bash analog to linux sh file downloader?

Tags: windows, linux, bash, sh

I try porting linux setup script to windows. In script I have file download like

```
ASL_DISTRO_SITE=surfnet.dl.sourceforge.net
BOOST_NAME=boost_1_44_0
BOOST_VERSION=1.44.0
    if [ ! -e $BOOST_DISTRO_NAME ]; then
        echo_run ${CURL_CMD} http://$ASL_DISTRO_SITE/project/boost/boost/$BOOST_VERSION/$BOOST_DISTRO_NAME -o $BOOST_DISTRO_NAME
    fi
```

How to port such part of script to windows .bat language? Are there any utils coming from MS by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a couple of missing items in the code you provide, but here is a best guess of how to proceed:

```
set ASL_DISTRO_SITE=surfnet.dl.sourceforge.net
set BOOST_NAME=boost_1_44_0
set BOOST_VERSION=1.44.0
set BOOST_DISTRO_NAME = xxxx?
set CURL_CMD="c:\program files\curl\curl.exe" ???

cd %BOOST_BASE_DIR%  

if NOT EXISTS %BOOST_DISTRO_NAME% (
    %CURL_CMD% ^
       http://$ASL_DISTRO_SITE/project/boost/boost/%BOOST_VERSION%/%BOOST_DISTRO_NAME% ^
       -o %BOOST_DISTRO_NAME%
)
```

I don't have an easy way to test this, so if it doesn't work, remove the open and close parens and the continuation char '^', and put all of the `%CURL_CMD% ...` command on the same line as the `if NOT EXISTS ...`.

So, you need to provide values for BOOST_BASE_DIR (which I have added as a var to the script), BOOST_DISTRO_NAME, CURL_CMD  .... AND ... you need to find out if you need `echo_run`, I don't think so. For `echo_run`, you have to look at your original script. I would guess that this is a function defined, and that is uses the `eval`. If that is true, the above may not work. Make a bat file without the IF NOT test, but with the all the `set ...` variables, and the `%CURL_CMD%`, run it and then add the output of the failure to you question above ;-)

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Kabumbus : I have edited in a few clarifications. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Download cURL for Windows from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)